# How to use URL Rewriting within foreach loop?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

```
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th pic</th>
            <th>rating</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach var="forumVO" items="${list}">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/forum/goforum?action=showImage&forum_no=${forumVO.forum_no}"></td>
                <td><%=request.getContextPath()%>/forum/goforum?action=showRating&forum_no=${forumVO.forum_no}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</form>
```

above is a simple code which both  tags uses url rewriting to send its information into the Servlet. but the one which has img tag is working good for showing the picture, but the second tag is not working properly, the html seems to see contents without <% %> and ${} as plain String objects, is there any ways to modify this code so the seconde tag can also sending its value to the Servlet?

Comment: you havnt used the anchor <a> tag

Comment: I probably did not describe my question clear. my question is that img tag can automaticly get all pictures while user into this page, but the one without img tag just shows plain text. I tried to use ancher tag but don't work, or can you show me how <a> will going to work on this problem? sorry I am just a beginner.

Comment: what the second URL suppose to show or what its doing?

Comment: it goes to Servlet and send following SQL to the database SELECT  count (*) from Ratings where forum_no = ?; it just basically count how many ratings in all forum_no and return the result to jsp.

Comment: so you mean its suppose to show a number not a plain text?

Comment: yes, the text show between <td> and </td> suppose to be something like 3 or 5, not /forum/goforum?action=showRating&forum_no=

Answer (score 2):

```
<c:forEach var="forumVO" items="${list}">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/forum/goforum?action=showImage&forum_no=${forumVO.forum_no}"></td>
                <td>${forumVO.forum_no}</td>
            </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

the `${forumVO.forum_no}` will print the number inside it no need to call the servlet again